# ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

Использую tensorflow в проекте с flask, при попытке переиспользовать модель получаю ошибку `ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph`, при создании новых моделей такой проблемы нет, _make_predict_function() не помогает.

Код

```
classifier_block_validation = None
classifier_image_type = None


def initialization_model():
   global classifier_block_validation
   global classifier_image_type
   classifier_block_validation = classifier_initialization(True)
   classifier_image_type = classifier_initialization(False)


def classifier_initialization(block_validation):
   classifier = Sequential()
   classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), 
   activation='relu'))
   classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   classifier.add(Flatten())
   classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
   if block_validation:
       classifier.add(Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid'))
       classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', 
       metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
       classifier.load_weights('network_blocks.h5')
   else:
       classifier.add(Dense(units=8, activation='sigmoid'))
       classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
       metrics=['accuracy'])
       classifier.load_weights('network.h5')
   return classifier


def recognition_image(image_path, block_validation):
   test_image = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(64, 64))
   test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
   test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
   test_image = test_image.astype('float') / 255.0
   if block_validation:
       return classifier_block_validation.predict(test_image)
   else:
       return classifier_image_type.predict(test_image)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   initialization_model()
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115946/tensor-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev пробовал так, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
....
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
session = K.get_session()
....
global graph
global session
if block_validation:
    with session.as_default():
        with graph.as_default():
            return classifier_block_validation.predict(test_image)
else:
    with session.as_default():
        with graph.as_default():
            return classifier_image_type.predict(test_image)
```